# Is it possible to programmatically get a shared Dropbox link without sending the user to the dropbox login page?

Tags: .net, vb.net, dropbox, dropnet

I’m developing a web application in vb.net 4.5 and using the third party library: `Dropnet`.
I’m wondering if is it possible to get a shared link from dropbox- programmatically- without having the user to login to dropbox.
thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is access to your dropbox files via the API, then you can request an access token from the App Console for the app you are working on.

See button here: [image: Generate Access Token]

If it is the users file you are trying to access, they have to auth via OAuth2 for security purposes.

Comment: yes, it is an access to my dropbox files via the API, would you be able to wrote me a sample how to set this access token?

Comment: In DropNet, it looks the shared link functionality is available via GetShare or GetShareAsync: http://dkdevelopment.net/what-im-doing/dropnet/